# What is the origin of language?

Tags: ancient-history, language

The use of language is one of the most conspicuous and diagnostic traits that distinguish Homo sapiens from other species. Unlike writing, spoken language leaves no trace.Can we get a direct method in trying to decipher the origins of language?

Comment: Studying the origins of language is more biological than historical, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: By definition this is not a history question, it is an anthropology question.

Comment: Although we entertain some anthropology questions here, I think this one is out of scope; the answer is not available through historical sources and methods. Fascinating question, but not, fundamentally a historical question.

Comment: I think you have the mistaken idea that language is some kind of invention, which it is not. If two children are raised in isolation by mute parents they will begin speaking to each other and will invent a language. The ability to create language is an innate human ability.

Comment: I'd consider trying to answer it, but I'm afraid I have no clue what you mean by "Can we get a direct method in...".

Comment: Actually, I don't think the study of anthropology has any answer for this either. Its an inherently cross-disciplinary issue, and I'm not sure there ever could be a more appropriate stack for a question on the origin of human language than this one.

Comment: We have absolutely no proof that other genus homo species _didn't_ talk...

Comment: A good recent book which explains what is known is Nicolas Wade, Before the Dawn, Penguin Press NY 2006. It is on pre-history in general, but has a very informative chapter on the language.

Comment: Definitely not history, and likely impossible to determine sans time machine.  We can't even tell when vocal cords appeared as soft-tissue changes are not preserved in the fossil record.